# Xamarin forms IOS project debugging not working

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin.ios

Hi I am building an app using xamarin forms Pcl project. When I set breakpoint in any PCL project file breakpoints hit when I run in debug mode.

But in IOS breakpoints are not working? If I set breakpoint in appdelegate.cs it works but as soon as it call App.cs in pcl project all breakpoints stop working.

I tried restarting my machine, visual studio.
I tried deleting bin and obj folders. But nothing works. I also tried to clean and rebuild it multiple times. Mac agent is connected and my app runs in simulator also but I need to debug it as it is stuck somewhere I need to know how I can enable debugging.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the breakpoint was hited in iOS project but not on PCL
I was able to resolve this using the workaround described here:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56893

Open the portable class library .csproj file in a text editor. For example, right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select Unload Project, and then right-click it again and select "Edit ...".
Under the PropertyGroup for the "Debug|AnyCPU" configuration, change the DebugType to:
portable

Comment: I tried to change the property of the PCL in project properties window but VS 2022 would not accept the change.  (It kept reverting it back to the Full level.)  Manually editing the csproj file worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Open the PCL .csproj in a text editor and take a look at the `Debug|AnyCPU` Property Group Condition, it must look like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
      <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
      <DebugType>full</DebugType>
      <Optimize>false</Optimize>
      <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
      <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If there is something different change it to match this one.
Open your project, clean it and run it.